# Why not check instance of java.lang.reflect.Field with java.util.List

Tags: java, reflection

I want check that field type is List or not, but that is giving an error:

```
Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#5-of ?> and 
     List
- Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#6-of ?> and 
     List
```

How can I solve this?

```
private void convert(Class<?> load) {

        Field[] fields = load.getDeclaredFields();
        int i = 0;
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Class<?> type = field.getType();
            if (type instanceof java.util.List) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private void convert(Class<?> load) {

    Field[] fields = load.getDeclaredFields();
    int i = 0;
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Class<?> type = field.getType();
        if (java.util.List.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        }
    }
}
```

instanceof operator is used only for instances!

Comment: actually type is child of List class. i want exact java.util.List class instances
here list children can be assign

Comment: public class B implements List{
}
the above loaded Field type is B so  it is giving true because it can be assignable . i want only List type i dont want B type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *declared type* of the field to match `java.util.List` exactly, you can use the expression `field.getType()==java.util.List.class` to test it.

Still, the *value* of that field is either `null` or an instance of a concrete class which implements the list `interface`.